# Python Extract PointProbes from Surface Contour Plot

Tags: python, scipy

I want to extract given point probes from a surface contour plot. Therefore I create the surface with following code snippet:

```
def createInterpolatedSurface():
  npts=1000
  xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x),npts)
  yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y),npts)
  xi,yi=np.meshgrid(xi,yi,indexing='xy')
  ui=scipy.interpolate.griddata((x,y),u,(xi,yi),method='linear')
return xi,yi,ui
```

My next step is to set up an array of points, with initSensorArray as nested Loop function, I am interested in:

So there is my main problem. I want to use the realistic physical coordinates of my points, not the ij indexing coordinates of the griddata interpolation function.

For example: Point(0.5,0.1) in physical space equals Pointg(100,125) in griddata ij indexing,.

How can I map the physical point coordinates to the griddata, extrapolate the points and map them back?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scipy'` [interpolate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html) functions in 2D,

```
from scipy import interpolate

x,y,u = createInterpolatedSurface()

#Create an interpolation function 
f = interpolate.interp2d(x, y, u, kind='cubic')

#Use interpolation function to get results
xpoint = 0.5
ypoint = 0.1
upoint = f(xpoint, ypoint)
```